# How can I mark an option as "selected" in Embedded Javascript Templating (EJS)

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose, ejs

I have created a function that allows a user to modify the data of another user. This also includes the option to adjust the role of a user. To do this I want the select form to show the current role of a user using the "selected" attribute. However, I can't figure out how to fix that.

This is the code of the select form in my `edit.ejs` file:

```js
<select name="role" id="role">
    <% roles.forEach((role) => { %>
        <option value="<%= role._id %>" <% if(role._id === user.role._id) { %> selected <% } %>>
            <%= role.name %>
        </option>
    <% }); %>
</select>
```

The code in my `userController.js` file:

```js
User.findById(req.params.id)
    .populate('role')
    .then((user) => {
        Role.find().then((roles) => {
            console.log(user);

            res.render('pages/users/edit', {
                title: 'Edit User',
                roles: roles,
                user: user,
            });
        });
    });
```

As my code now looks, none of the options in the select form has a selected attribute.
The `console.log(user)` shows the correct data, so that shouldn't be the problem.

Hope someone can help me
Thanks

Comment: have you checked this post yet https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34878180/html-select-option-with-ejs ?

Comment: I have, but then somehow all option tags have a selected attribute..

Answer (score 0):

You can hardcode a value in just vanilla html by giving a value to the select menu; however, if you want the value to be dynamic using ejs you can do something like:

```
<select class="fancy-select" id="vendorID" name="vendorID" value="<%= data.vendorID %>" required onchange="updateCollections(this);update_category()">
  <option value="">Choose:</option>
    <% data.vendors.forEach(vendor => { %>
      <option value=<%= vendor.vendorID%> class="">
        <%= vendor.vendorName%> 
      </option>
    <% }) %>
</select>
```

Comment: Are you sure this is possible? Because I've tried it, but nothing changes .. In addition, they explain in this post that it is not possible to give a '' value '' attribute to the <select> tag. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5589629/value-attribute-on-select-tag-not-selecting-default-option

Comment: Yes I am positive as I use this method on my site. I accidentally had an underscore (for white space slurping) which may have been contributing to the problem if you had copy and pasted my code... otherwise I would make sure the your values that you are passing are not null/undefined...

Comment: I changed the example to verbatim code that works on my website.

Comment: I have literally copied everything and it still does not show the correct default option. I'm sure the values I'm passing are not null/undefined because I put them in a console.log() and got the correct data. Besides that, I can guarantee that I know what I am doing :) I applied the same way in a Laravel project and it worked there, but I don't know why my first option with the if statement did not work in this project. It's my first time using EJS so I thought I maybe was overlooking something.